# How to get text co-ordinate x & y value present in GUI using robotframework or using python

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, mouse, pyautogui

I want to select the text alarm first, & I need to get the co-ordinate of that text alarm

Once co-ordinate is fixed, I want to move the mouse to the right

I'm trying in below ways, but I am not finding exact co-ordinates od the text alarm

Click On Control

```
[Arguments]    ${element}

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    15x    5    Click Element    //*[text()='${element}']

Selenium2Library.mouse over    //*[text()='${element}']

${width}    ${height} =    Get Element Size    //*[text()='${element}']

${x}=    Get Horizontal Position    //*[text()='${element}']

${y}=    Get Vertical Position    //*[text()='${element}']

click element at coordinates    //*[text()='${element}']    ${x}    ${y}

${width}    ${height} =    Selenium2Library.Get Window Size
```

Please help to me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinate of an element using javascript:

```
${Top}    Execute Javascript    var element=document.querySelector("yourElementCSSSelector"); var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); return rect.top

${Left}    Execute Javascript    var element=document.querySelector("yourElementCSSSelector"); var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); return rect.left
```

This will give you the top-left coordinates of the element

Comment: Executing JavaScript:
var element=document.querySelector("//*[text()='titanDiameterNgStatistics']"); var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(); return rect.top 
19:26:56.270 FAIL InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '//*[text()='titanDiameterNgStatistics']' is not a valid selector.
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64) 
I'm getting this issue

Comment: use css instead of xpath